# WindowsAppSDK resource file modification requires rebuild

Tags: desktop-application, winui-3

In WinUI 3 C++ Desktop project I am facing a problem. Every time I modify the localization resource files I need to rebuild the full project.

It's recommended to prepare a post-build command to overcome this issue.

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/mrtcore/localize-strings
```

I am not sure how the MakePri.exe command works for generating the resource.pri file for an unpackaged app.

Comment: Did you mean [Loading strings in unpackaged applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/mrtcore/localize-strings#loading-strings-in-unpackaged-applications)?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Yes. I don't have any config files. The generated PRI file is resources.pri after build. For every modification, I need to rebuild the full project. 
makepri new /pr <PROJECTROOT> /cf <PRICONFIG> /of resources.pri how to omit the /cf and use default?

Comment: NO. *The <PRICONFIG> must omit the "<packaging>" section so that all resources are bundled in a single resources.pri file. If using the default MakePri.exe configuration file created by createconfig, you need to delete the "<packaging>" section manually after it is created.* You can [create a new, initialized PRI config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/makepri-exe-command-options#createconfig-command) for your project and delete [Packaging element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/makepri-exe-configuration#packaging-element).

Comment: Also, accroding to [New command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/makepri-exe-command-options#new-command), `/ConfigXml(cf)` is a **Required** Parameter.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT After removing the <packaging> section manually I am getting a duplicated entry error. But nothing is duplicated. Is it somehow unable to separate the language en and de resources?
Language Qualifiers: en-us,de-de

ERROR: PRI175: 0x80073b0f - Processing Resources failed with error: Duplicate Entry.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT It worked with your earlier hint. You can post it as a reply. It will help others. I will accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can know that `/ConfigXml(cf)` is a **Required** Parameter under MakePri.exe [New command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/makepri-exe-command-options#new-command). So, you need to [create a new, initialized PRI config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/makepri-exe-command-options#createconfig-command) for your project.

While according to [Loading strings in unpackaged applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/mrtcore/localize-strings#loading-strings-in-unpackaged-applications),

> - The <PRICONFIG> must omit the "<packaging>" section so that all
>   resources are bundled in a single resources.pri file. **If using the
>   default MakePri.exe configuration file created by createconfig, you
>   need to delete the "<packaging>" section manually after it is created**.